# How to add code that runs after application launch in EXTjs MVC architecture

Tags: extjs

I know that `init()` executes before the application launch function is called. But I have some code that should be rendered only after the whole application has been launched. Please guide me with this. I need to write it in controller class of my MVC architecture application.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main', {

    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

     models: [
        'Leave'
    ],
    stores: [
        'MyJsonStore'
    ],

    views: [
        'Login',
        'MyViewport',
        'ManageColumn'
    ],

    init:function(){

        this.control({
            'managecolumn':{
                  afterrender:this.allowEdit
        }
    });
            },

         allowEdit:function(){
        console.log(Ext.get('edit'));

       }

});
```

I am getting null for `Ext.get('edit')` but when I enter same command in console
I get a positive response.

Comment: what code do you have so far? you're not giving us much to go on.

Comment: @cobaco : yes i will provide the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what 'edit' element is and how it is set - it is difficult to give you a precise answer. 
However, take a look at this MVC example that uses launch function on the Application class http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/wULET/

The viewport is created on `launch`, and you could potentially do what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for reply, edit is a HTML element, it appears that it is not rendered after launch of application also. i have got a workaround, but i am not yet convinced with my present solution, it deviates from MVC philosophy. I tried onLaunch method but to no avail.

Comment: I think you are confused about the timing of events and what launch event means. also you need to provide the mechanism by which the edit html element is generated.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the launch function in Ext.application.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-launch

onLaunch works for me in the controllers though...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding an [onLaunch](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-onLaunch) method?

Comment: This should work, it does for me in my applications. I use it all the time.